# Image not displaying in image control

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'm showing an image in image control. For that I have created File Upload control of TextBox and button. And storing image in projects Images folder.Image is uploading very well. But it always needs to include in project then only I'm getting image displayed. Is there any solution to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the Silverlight application is running LOCAL in the user's browser. It cannot (easily) access files on the webserver that you upload. Files you include in the project work because they are compiled into the dll which is downloaded to the browser.

To dynamically access files uploaded to the server you need to implement some kind of WCF service to send it back. I don't know if you can easily "download" a file into a Silverlight App with a URL. Silerlight is pretty tight on what you can and cannt do...